# Interaction with AFrame Click-to-show

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

So I wanna make an interactive bar charts with aframe. For example clicking the bar showing it's details. Like in the glitch here https://glitch.com/~salty-partner-1

The problem is, as you can see, when clicking the first bar, the 2nd bar text will also show up. My question is, should I make a new **registerComponent** for every barchart (ex: text-show1, text-show2 etc.) or is there other way?

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("text-show", {
            init: function() {
            let toggle = false
              this.el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                let box = document.querySelectorAll(".clickable")
                box.forEach(function(el) {
                    el.setAttribute("visible", toggle)
                })
                toggle = !toggle
              })
            }
          })
```

I did register a new component for 2-3 bars, but I have like 20 bars. So registering 20 components is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass into the schema, what element you want to toggle visible. `text-show="target: #text1"`.

Here's a component that does this for you: https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/event-set#aframe-event-set-component `event-set__click="_target: #text1; visible: true"`

Here's an advanced example of UI and clickables and stuff: https://glitch.com/~aframe-building-ui

Comment: Haven't touch schema just yet, prob gonna look into it. 
As for the components, i tried. It's just show the text. But I want to toggle between visible or not, or shoud I just use the mouseup/down?